# Getting the post instance in Django class based views

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-class-based-views

I currently use a function based view to let users write comments on posts, but I'm trying to convert it to class based views

Function views.py

```
def comment(request, pk):  
  form = CommentForm(request.POST)
  # Post instance
  post_instance = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid:
      obj = form.save(commit=False)
      obj.commenter = request.user
      obj.post = post_instance
      obj.save()
      return redirect('/')
  else:
    messages.error(request, 'Comment Failed')
    
  return render(request, 'comment.html', {'form': form})
```

Class views.py

```
class CommentView(FormView):
  template_name = 'comment.html'
  form_class = CommentForm
  success_url = '/'

  def get_object(self):
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    post_instance = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return post_instance

  def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.commenter = self.request.user
    obj.post = post_instance
    obj.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

I'm trying to implement the same logic for saving the comment but I get the error: name 'post_instance' is not defined

get_object() is returning the 'post_instance' variable but I can't access it.
Could you guys show me where I'm doing a mistake, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
class CommentView(FormView):
  template_name = 'comment.html'
  form_class = CommentForm
  success_url = '/'

  def get_object(self):
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    post_instance = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return post_instance

  def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.commenter = self.request.user
    obj.post = self.get_object()
    obj.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```